# Cursor disappears after completion in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to do some code blocks in emacs org-mode.
What I am do is

- press C-c C-, s
- write sh :session. at this point i have

```
#+begin_src sh :session[cursor]
#+end_src              ^
```

- than press Enter and got some selector in modeline, that looks like autocomplition
- Once I make selection my cursor *disapears* and I have to reopen file to have it back

How can I prevent cursor from disappearing?

How can I debug what exactly happening when I press enter?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew Is there a way to debug behavior? I found for example that something change cursor-type on nil. Can I set break point on function invokation? Bisecting seems unpromising and tedious.

Comment: 1. Bisecting is quick - it's a binary search. As with any binary search, it seems slow *at first*. 2. You can use `M-x debug-on-entry` and other ways to open the Lisp debugger - see the Elisp manual, node [Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ivy? If yes, [this issue](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1732) might be helpful to further dissect the problem.
Also, completion in src-block [doesn't work well](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/13465#issuecomment-619544999) if using helm or ivy.

### Tl;Dr

set `org-src-tab-acts-natively` to `nil` with

```
(setq org-src-tab-acts-natively nil)
```

However, This will disable the completion.